# detect inside iphone app if phone has moved to stand by mode

Tags: iphone, background

Please clarify me on the following problem:

When my app is running in background mode, can I detect the moment when the phone enters the stand by mode?If yes, tell me how.Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the app is moved to background you can detect it by the below method.
But once the app is in Background then there is no way you can detect any of its state.

So For detecting the StandBy mode your app has to be in foreground.

In case your App is running then the below methods are your friend ..

For Stand by

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

For Background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application ;

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: I know these methods are called.The problem how I detect that my phone is in stand by state?...the code comes written in these methods, i know that.

Comment: @george, you should read documentation of apple, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive)

{

    // Background code

}
```